# What is use of require with webpack?

Tags: angular, webpack

I am trying to learn angular2 with help of ng-book2.
In the app.ts there is a code snippet that I do not understand :

```
require('../css/styles.css');
require('../css/semantic.min.css');
require('../images/ng-book-2-minibook.png');
require('../images/favicon-32x32.png');
require('../images/favicon.ico');
```

1. Why they require css, png files?
2. Why they do this why?

Comment: http://blog.andrewray.me/webpack-when-to-use-and-why/ answers this in depth

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of adding links for your css in html you can import them in js directly and work with them and webpack bundle them in your build. It make lots of easy to work and give you a nice work flow. You use webpack as mudule bundler and that is also a part of webpack.  Say you have a component and you want to give some style so you make a style sheet but instead of declaring it in html you just require it in that component and use it.

### An example

```
import { Component , ViewEncapsulation } from "@angular/core";

@Component({
    directives: [],
    encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None,
    selector: "sg-app",
    styles: [require("./app.styles.css").toString()],//importing styles here
    templateUrl: "./app.template.html",
})
export class AppComponent {
 public id: string = "fd";
}
```

### Template

`<footer class="footer">Mr.JS</footer>` using here

### My style

```
.footer {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  padding: 1rem;
  background-color: #efefef;
  text-align: center;
}
```

### What require do?

It bundle `CSS`, `JS` and `HTML` into one. It's like importing a library.

Comment: What do you mean include into component? For example ts file?

Comment: Thanks so much @MrJSingh